# AWS Application Load Balancer health checks fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an ecs fargate cluster with an ALB to route the traffic to. The docker containers are listening on port 9000.

My containers are accessible over the alb dns name via https. That works. But they keep getting stopped/deregistered from the target group and restarted only to be in unhealthy state immediately after they are registered in the target group.

The ALB has only one listener on 443. 
The security groups are set up so that the `sg-alb` allows outbound traffic on port 9000 to `sg-fargate` and `sg-fargate` allows all inbound traffic on port 9000 from `sg-alb`.

The target group is also setup to use port 9000.

I'm not sure what the problem is, or how to debug it.

Everything is set up with cdk. Not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: I added "Allow All Traffic from/to everywhere" rules to both sg. Now I get healthy instances in only one of my two AZ/subnets. The instances in the other AZ are still shown as unhealthy and drained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out this was not a problem with security groups. It was just coincidental, that it worked at the time when I changed the security groups.

It seems the containers aren't starting fast enough to accept connections from the alb when it starts the health checks.

What helped:

- changing `healthCheckGracePeriod` to two minutes
- tweaking the healthcheck paremeters for the target group, `interval`, `unhealthyThreshold`, `healthyThreshold`

Also, in my application logs it looks like the service gets two health check requests at once. Per default the `unhealthy threshold` is set to 2. So maybe the service was marked unhealthy only after one health check.

Comment: Hi @Saskia, could you please share the configuration you used for healthcheck parameters? My configuration is interval=5 mins, timeout=1 min, healthyThresholdCount=5, unhealthyThresholdCount=3. Application runs fine for around 30 mins and then health starts draining even when tasks are just running fine and no issues seen in logs. I have used exactly same aws resources as you did with ECS Fargate cluster and ALB with necessary security groups. Want to mention that application runs fine and responds to api request for those 30 mins when health is good.

Comment: @horizon7 I'm sorry. We don't have this problem anymore. So i don't have the numbers anymore. But your problem seems to be different anyway, as my services wouldn't even startup correctly.